# How to create array in document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, html

AS title, I want to create array in document.getElementById because my id is come from repeat region. Below is my javascript and html.

```js
<script type ="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('table tbody tr').click(function(){
    
    var PurchaserID = window.opener.document.getElementById("PurchaserID");
    var n = 5;
            PurchaserID.value = document.getElementById("test[n]").innerText;
    alert(PurchaserID.value);
    
     window.close();
  
   });
  });
</script>
```

```html
  <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
      <td id = "test[<?php echo $row_Purchaser['ID'];?>]"  align="center" ><?php echo $row_Purchaser['ID'];?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row_Purchaser['Name']; ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row_Purchaser['IC']; ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row_Purchaser['Handphone']; ?></td>
       </tr>
   <?php } while ($row_Purchaser = mysql_fetch_assoc($Purchaser)); ?>
```

Any problem of my program. Why I can't get the value test[n] to test[5] even I create var n =5; May I know how to solve it. Thanks if you could me !!

Comment: What is you're question? I am having a really, really hard time understanding.

Comment: of course, the simplest way in the code you posted is `document.getElementById("test[5]")` - because it's all hard coded anyway so there's no reason to overcomplicate it

Comment: @nicovank I create var n =5 ; then i do this -> document.getElementById("test[n]") but  test[n] can't go to test[5]..

Comment: @JaromandaX Ya, I knew, but then I can't get another id. For example : test[1],test[2], test[3].

Comment: use `test[1]` or `test[2]` ... it all looks hardcoded to me, so why overcomplicate it ... perhaps post **actual** code you are having an issue with rather than code that has a simple solution

Comment: change `"test[n]"` to `"test[" + n + "]"`

Comment: Yes! change "test[n]" to "test[" + n + "]" help me get the value !! Thanks you very much @JaromandaX

Comment: you can change id by class, if you have <td class="test">, the selector will be getElementsByClassName() which return you an array of element

Comment: @JaromandaX You're correct. Even I use the for loop, it is hard code also...